Units in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$.
I have started studying Huybrech's Complex Geometry. Given the sheaf of holomorphic functions $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n}$, he states that the units of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$ are exactly the $f\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$ such that $f(0)\neq 0$. I see this clearly. However, he later states that $Z(f)$ is empty for such units, meaning, if I am correct, that no representative $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ of a unit in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$ has a zero in $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$.
I supose the equivalence between both statements must be obtained through some complex analysis result, but I cannot come up with it.

The title is missing a $.

This is not complex analysis but simply continuity. If $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is such that $f(0) \neq 0$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ included in $U$ such that $f_{|V}$ doesn't vanish. Since $f$ and $f_{|V}$ define the same element of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$, $Z(f) = \emptyset$ where $Z(f)$ is seen as a germ of analytic subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ at $0$.
Similarly, you can argue that any non-empty germ of analytic subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ at $0$ must contain $0$ since it is closed and in contains point arbitrarily close to $0$. Thus, $Z(f) \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow f(0) = 0$.

Maybe my problem comes from a bad understanding of $Z(f)$. Wouldn't the argument above just imply $Z(f)\cap U$ to be empty? And, if not, why can't we always take, given some $z\in Z(f)$, the function $f|_{V}$ for $V$ not including $z$, in order to conclude $z\not\in Z(f)$?

Oh, I get it now. The germ $Z(f)$ is a class of sets, not a set. Thank you!

Yes, it is a germ. You can define it with the equivalence relation $(U_1,Z_1) \sim (U_2,Z_2)$ if there is a $U_3 \subset U_1 \cap U_2$ containing $0$ such that $Z_1 \cap U_3 = Z_2 \cap U_3$. Here, $(U,Z)$ denotes an open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ and $Z$ an analytic subset of $U$.
